# Using jQuery Plugins - Preferred method

Tags: jquery-plugins

Not sure how to word this but, not considering how complicated it is to build, which is preferred by people, does it matter and what's the advantages and disadvantages of using:

```
$(ele).plugin("method", options);
```

as opposed to

```
$(ele).plugin.method(options);
```

Thanks

Comment: There is not a major difference, one calls the other..while preferred as I see in most cases an I use is the 1st case of yours code..

Answer (score 0):

I think the second way may be out of performance because it is related to a object notable version of JavaScript. So, it may reference a null member or type when accessed.

The first way is easier because it uses only the arguments in a method.